# Jquery DatePicker dateformat change

Tags: c#, jquery, date-format

i am working in C#  with j query. in my work i am using datepicker in that i get a doubt,

my problem is, i am got date from datepicker den bind in Textbox, i need after get the textbox date

format have to change, any one give a solution,

Comment: Which date picker are you using,Please give a link from where you got that.There must be a provision to change the format.

Comment: besides the english problems. could you show some code? so we can help you? I guess this is a js question and has nothing to do with c# isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

there are many datepickers available with jQuery. but I would go with jQuery UI builtin [one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/):

and then you could set the date format like this:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings )
```

or use different methods ( a lot of them) to customize it for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use:
1)After select value from `datepicker` you change format like this.

```
    getDate() // Returns date
    getMonth() // Returns the month
    getFullYear() // Returns the year
    var d ="Your Date From date picker";
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var desirersult = (curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year); //how you want to display.
```

2)Before selecting `datepicker` you set a format:

```
$('#datepicker ').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the date when jQuery is executed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".DatepickerInput").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
```

Or when you add the date to a textbox do the following:

```
TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString("d");
```

Use [Date Formatting in C#](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/23/Date-Formatting-in-CSharp) to format your date appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dateFormat`

like this

```
$('#ControlId').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' });

OR 

$('#ControlId').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Comment: after got date from date picker to text box.then while retrieving the date from text box.i need to change date format.